# Can't find index.html when bundling Node.js server with Webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm trying to setup webpack to bundle my backend code.

My webpack config looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

const client = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    'app': [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './client/index.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
    })
  ]
}

const server = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    'app': [
      './server/server.js'
    ]
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/server'),
    filename: 'server.bundle.js'
  }
}

module.exports = [client, server]
```

If I run the non-webpack server.js, everything works fine. However if I run the webpack bundled server.bundle.js, express throws:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/index.html'`

Both server files are in the same directory. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: can I see your client configuration?

Comment: @AliDoustkani added

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it's not explicitly stated in webpack's documentation but you need to configure a "node" property when using express

Ex. add this to your config

```
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false,   // if you don't put this is, __dirname
    __filename: false,  // and __filename return blank or /
  },
```